# Intepretation of generated $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm readying Probability with Martingales by David Williams, and I encountered the following discussion in section 3.13. It says that if we have a collection of random variables $(Y_\gamma:\gamma \in C)$ on a probability triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, then the $\sigma$-algebra generated by these random variables are precisely the events $F$ such that for every $\omega$, one can decide if $\omega\in F$ based on $Y_\gamma(\omega), \gamma \in C$. I'm trying to prove this but I can't see how it can be done. Can anyone please help?

Comment: That statement doesn't seems like something one should prove, but rather like something one is supposed to make up is mind on.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x:=Y(\omega)$ for some chosen $\omega \in \Omega $, then as every $F\in \sigma (Y)$ is of the form $F=Y^{-1}(A)$ for some Borel set $A$, then if $x\in A$ you knows that $\omega \in F$. And viceversa: if $x\notin A$ then necessarily $\omega \notin F$.